# a good Linux based remote IP and application monitoring tool?

Tags: monitoring

besides Ganglia, statsd/graphite and Shrinken and preferably free.

anyone have any ideas?

TIA

Comment: Please clarify/amplify/narrow-down your requirements, restrictions, and any other relevant criteria. Possibly explain why Ganglia, statsd, and Shrinken don't do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You mean [Nagios](http://www.nagios.org/), possibly with NagiosGrapher?  With some work, you can almost make it do anything.  But it's possibly overkill for you needs.  Can you clarify what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

There are several.  Nagios is my favorite, but ZenOSS has some momentum as well.  The Nagios is very powerful but requires a fair amount of finesse to configure.  ZenOSS purports to be easier to set up.